# how to install nginx?

Tags: nginx

I am trying to install `dotplant2` in my system and for that i need to install `nginx` and i followed a step that `dotplant2` documentaion has provided and when i try to restart `nginx` as the way the documentation has explained  it fails to restart and when i entered this command

```
sudo nginx -t
```

Here is the error message:

```
nginx:[emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)   
in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/dotplant2-host:20
```

how can i resolve this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the error, in dotpalant2 documentation it says to change

`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/dotplant2-host`

as below

```
server {
    listen 80;

    # NOTE: Replace with your path here
    root /home/user/dotplant2/application/web;
    index index.php;

    # NOTE: Replace with your hostname
    server_name dotplant2.dev;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi.conf;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
       deny all;
    }
}
```

in there

`include fastcgi.conf;`

but in our nginx folder there is no `fastcgi.conf` so we have to change as

`include fastcgi_params;`

then all are work nicely for ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest fix is to create that missing file in the /etc/nginx/ directory...

`nano /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf`

...and write this line in it:

`include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;`